# Having trouble with a form validation plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this jQuery plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation so I can validate a form I am making. But it does not seem to validate the phone field. Can anyone help me understand what did I do wrong?

This is my code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var validator
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     validator = jQuery("#participateform").validate();
 });

function sendRequest(){ 
        var validform=validator.form();       
        if(validform)
        {
            alert("Form is valid");
        }
}
</script>

<form id="participateform" >
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">fullname</div>
            <div class="td">
                <input type="text" value="" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">your e-mail </div>
            <div class="td">
                <input type="text" value="" id="e-mail" name="e-mail" class="required email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">area</div>
            <div class="td">
                <select id="area" name="area"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">Phone 1</div>
            <div class="td">
                <input type="text" value="" id="phone" name="phone" class="required phone"/>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">Phone 1</div>
            <div class="td">
                <input type="text" value="" id="phone2" name="phone2" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="submit" onclick="sendRequest()"> 
</form>
```

Comment: See [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) there is a `jQuery.validator.addMethod("phone", function(pnumber)` code for that extend validation for phone

Comment: Thanx Alex Ball seems that if I add this on the ready jQuery.validator.addMethod("phone", function(pnumber) { 
   var stripped = pnumber.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');
   if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped)) || !(stripped.length == 10)) {
    return false;
   }else{
    return true;
   }
  }, "Please specify a valid phone number");

works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Source code to the library suggest that this library uses the following Validation Rules for Phones:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUK', function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+|-/g,'');
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid phone number');

jQuery.validator.addMethod('mobileUK', function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+|-/g,'');
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^((0|\+44)7(0|4|5|6|7|8|9){1}\d{2}\s?\d{6})$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid mobile number');

//Matches UK landline + mobile, accepting only 01-3 for landline or 07 for mobile to exclude many premium numbers
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phonesUK', function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+|-/g,'');
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(0[1-3]{1}[0-9]{8,9})$/) || phone_number.match(/^(07[5-9]{1}[0-9]{7,8})$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid uk phone number');
```

So instead of doing this :

```
<input type="text" value="" id="phone" name="phone" class="required phone"/>
```

Try this for a US phone number:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="phone" name="phone" class="required phoneUS"/>
```

Or this for a UK phone number:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="phone" name="phone" class="required phoneUK"/>
```

OR this for a UK Mobile Phone Number

```
<input type="text" value="" id="phone" name="phone" class="required mobileUK"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

What kinda of validation fails on phone?

A quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L274) revels a lack for phone as validation class.

**EDIT**

You need to add a custom rule:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.validator.addMethod("phone", function(value, element) {
    //Any code that will return TRUE or FALSE
    return /^(\d+){10}$/.test(value);
  },
  "Error message");

});
```

Comment: well I need it to validate if its a 10 digit phone number

Answer (score 1):

Try to lookk [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods), seems that you're should use another built-in validation method, like `digits()` or `phoneUS()`

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned, there is no validation for phone. You may use jQuery.validator.addMethod() to define your own (even by regex or however you want), it is well documented.

Also see this:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js